# Debugger console is not opening

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have created a simple hello world application in xcode using the command line utility. When i click on Build and Run. program successfully builds. I  can see a message at status bar
"Debugging of HelloMac ended normally"

But debugger console on which Hello World message should appear is not opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Xcode` => `Preferences` => `Debugging` => `On Startup` => `Show Console`:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/561d0aa7dc.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/561d0aa7dc.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Check your Xcode Preferences, under Debugging, the "On Start" setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try shift-command-R to open the console, it doesn't open automatically as far as I know unless you use the all-in-one view and choose 'Debug' instead of 'Run'.